# Tkinter - Scan and list all the images in a folder and load them

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to design a level editor for a MAME game with Tkinter.
In a folder I have 256 images that I want to work with and use them as Radiobutton images.

Right now I am loading them one after another in order to use them like this:

```
img_00 = PhotoImage(file="./gfx/00.png")
img_01 = PhotoImage(file="./gfx/01.png")
img_02 = PhotoImage(file="./gfx/02.png")
```

and so on.

Even If I am a beginner I know that this method works but it is not a good practice.
I would like to load them with a for loop but cannot code that.

I have tried

```
img_list=[]
my_folder= os.listdir('gfx/')
img=PhotoImage(Image.open('./gfx/'))
n_row = 0
n_col= 0

for x in my_folder:
    n_col +=1
    if n_col > 16:
        n_row +=1
        n_col = 1
    img_list.append(img)
    radio_button = Radiobutton(C, image=img, indicatoron=0)
    radio_button.grid(row=n_row, column=n_col)
```

and I get: PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: './gfx/'

I have also tested:

```
img_list=[]
my_folder= os.listdir('gfx/')
img=PhotoImage() ################ no path to folder ##############
n_row = 0
n_col= 0

for x in my_folder:
    n_col +=1
    if n_col > 16:
        n_row +=1
        n_col = 1
    img_list.append(img)
    radio_button = Radiobutton(C, image=img, indicatoron=1)
    radio_button.grid(row=n_row, column=n_col)
```

No images are loaded but I obtained 256 radiobuttons which corresponds to the number of images I'd like to used (I've also tried to remove one image from  my folder and I obtain 255 radiobuttons).

What I am doing wrong?

Best,
Donatello

Comment: In the loop, you need to create a separate `PhotoImage` for each image file in folder, and attach it to each `Radiobutton`. Don't try to store each one in differently named variable, store them all in a single list.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for you reply. What do you mean with "create a separate PhotoImage for each image file in folder"?

Comment: I meant create a new one for each image file named `x`, *inside* the `for` loop. You code attempts to put the same one in every column of every row. Completely get rid of the one outside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

I post the solution I've found.

```
img_list=[]
path = "./gfx" # my folder
n_row = 0
n_col = 0
index = 0
x = IntVar()
for f in os.listdir(path):
    img_list.append(ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(os.path.join(path,f))))
    n_col +=1
    index +=1
    if n_col > 9:
        n_row +=1
        n_col = 1
    radio_button = Radiobutton(C, image=img_list[index-1], indicatoron=0, bd=2, variable = x, value = index)
    radio_button.grid(row=n_row, column = n_col)
```